# Wait/Sleep inside functions

Tags: actionscript-3, system, sleep, wait

I was wondering how to use a Sleep/Wait system **inside** functions in AS3 without pausing the whole project at once, here is how I usually do it:

```
function doubleBoom():void
{
    boom();
    setTimeout(boom, 1);// calls boom after a 1 second delay
}
```

And here is how I want to do it:

```
function doubleBoom():void
{
    boom();
    wait(1);// this function doesn't exist, that's what im trying to solve
    boom();
}
```

This method would have numerous advantages for me such as increasing readability and allowing me to inline delayed functions. It is based on the *Trigger editor* from *Warcraft 3 World Editor*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can have only one thread in AS3, there is no way to achieve that without stoping the whole project. There are a number of things (e.g. loading something from network) that can be done in asynchronous way, but if your particular operation does not support asynchronous operation then using timer is the best way to do that.

It is possible to write a wrapper class that will encapsulate the timer handling so that you don't need to write timer code many times. You can write something like `RepeatTaskManager` which will take the function object to execute, any required parameters for that function, the delay between successive calls of the function and the number of times you want to call the function. In that way you can have timer code only in one place and use `RepeatTaskManager` easily whenever you need this kind of feature.

Comment: Voted down as this does not answer the question, right answer: not possible.

Comment: @BotMaster did you miss the part "there is **no way** to achieve that without stoping the whole project"? My first line clearly says that its not possible. Rest of the answer just points to a possible way to manage the timer code easily which could be useful if you have many such codes.